# Java proxy connection

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

Im creating several proxy sockets and binding them to another server. Can i create more than 1 instance of the proxy socket? For example having 4 Sockets using the same proxy?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Your browser for example opens a lot of sockets, even if it is through a proxy.